# nginx rewrite two url segments

Tags: php, nginx, url-rewriting

I have it almost working, just cant get it the last inch.

What I'm trying to do is

https://example.com/ap/variable1/variable2/

and have it go to

https://example.com/ap/index.php?server=$1&guild=$2

where the variables are optional. What I have now is

```
location /ap/ {
    rewrite "^/ap/(.*)/(.*)$" "/ap/index.php?server=$1&guild=$2" last;
}
```

This mostly works, if I go to the url with the end slash it makes both the variable into one without it, it loads just fine.

if I change the rule to

```
location /ap/ {
    rewrite "^/ap/(.*)/(.*)/$" "/ap/index.php?server=$1&guild=$2" last;
}
```

I get a 404 when trying to goto the first variable, is there a way to have my cake and eat it too, what am I missing here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first capture is greedy, which means that it will capture everything up to the last `/` (rather than the first `/` as you intended). You could make the capture non-greedy by using `*?` instead of `*`.

But if the captures are not intended to capture `/`, you should use the `[^/]` character class instead. For example:

```
rewrite ^/ap/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?$ /ap/index.php?server=$1&guild=$2 last;
```

The trailing `/` has also been made optional. See [this useful resource](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refquick.html) on regular expressions.

Comment: You are the best! only fix I had to do was wrap it in quotes

`rewrite "^/ap/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?$" "/ap/index.php?server=$1&guild=$2" last;`

Comment: `nginx` does not require quotes unless braces are involved. I presume this is a constraint of your deployment system.